# Correct Mel Spectogram Generation

Tags: classification, audio-recognition

I recently discovered [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/audio-classification-with-pytorchs-ecosystem-tools-5de2b66e640c) that details moving audio classification into the image domain and I was intrigued enough to dive in and take a closer look.

A good portion of the article details how to pre-process a dataset prior to training. I've already spent a couple of evenings working on this and have a small application that scans through a directory and produces the spectrograms. In the article audio is standardised to summed mono and converted.

The issue is since I'm so new to this I'm unsure that I'm producing these spectograms in a state where they are really fit for use. Hence the question.

I've run my tool over my input data already, trained an MS.NET ResNet model over a tiny dataset I've prepped and all things considered, it actually got most of tests I ran on it correctly. It's clearly not ready but the fact it got as many right as it did has already surprised me so I know I'm not a million miles away.

The code in the article is all Python so I've had to find .NET replacements and get as close to the articles methodology as I can get.

His code for generating spectrograms is:

```
melspectogram_transform = torchaudio.transforms.MelSpectrogram(
  sample_rate=fixed_sample_rate, n_mels=128)
melspectogram_db_transform = torchaudio.transforms.AmplitudeToDB()

melspectogram = melspectogram_transform(audio_mono)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(melspectogram.squeeze().numpy(), cmap='hot')
 
melspectogram_db=melspectogram_db_transform(melspectogram)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(melspectogram_db.squeeze().numpy(), cmap='hot')
```

Which produces graphs like this:

[image]

After some experimentation I arrived at this code:

```
(double[] audio, int sampleRate) = ReadWav(_sourceFile);
var sg = new SpectrogramGenerator(sampleRate, fftSize: 8192, stepSize: 500, maxFreq: 22050, fixedWidth: 500);
sg.SetColormap(Colormap.Magma);
sg.Add(audio);

// Create a Mel Spectrogram
var bmp = sg.GetBitmapMel(250, intensity:5, dB: true);

bmp.Save(Path.Combine(_targetDirectory, $"{_fileName}.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
```

Which produces graphs like this:

[image]

Which to my untrained eye looks like it should be good to go and, from my initial testing, looks like given a decent sized dataset, should work.

The library I'm using is this one [swharden/Spectrogram](https://github.com/swharden/Spectrogram)

A potential issue is that whilst I am pre-processing the training audio files are not standardised in length (hence the fixed width parameter). This seems to be working as some of my graphs look like this (padded):

[image]

When I was testing I tested quite a few files where this was the case and the identification worked so I don't think this is a major problem but again, I'm very new to this and most likely not in a position to really critique and assess it as well as the folks here.

Is there anything I can or should do to produce better input images or does this already seem like a reasonable approach?

I clearly need a much larger data set but want to ensure I have a fighting chance of success before leaving my machine number crunching for days!

**UPDATE**

I have now built a working pipeline to standardise all audio files to 16bit 44.1Khz mono files either clipped or padded to 4 seconds. These are then converted to mels and look like this:

[image]

I'm sure there is a significant problem with these mels as it looks like the image is rolling vertically.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Using the magma colormap only makes sense, when you present the spectrogram to humans. Using grayscale is more appropriate, IMHO. What's the task you are trying to solve? Depending on it, you might want to choose different frequency ranges, number of mel bands and hop (step) sizes.

Comment: Ahhhh. Greyscale that does actually make a lot of sense, even to my noob brain. I'm training a set on audio samples like synthesisiers and drum loops. I've got about 70,000 files prepped so far which should already give some useful results and brief experiements and tests are promising already. I'm limited by the control the spectrogram tool I'm using I think. Lots of varying length files at the moment hence creating a fixed width image. I did expect the padding at the end rather than the start though. Possibly an issue with my step size I'm guessing at the moment.

Comment: With "what the task you are trying to solve", I was trying to find out, is this, for example, a multi-class multi-label classification task, where you are feeding the network an image and expect it to spit out, for example, the present instruments. So in other words, what do you want the network to classify and how?

Comment: Ahhh. I'm working with a set of audio files. Today I finished my pipeline to resample to 16bit mono 4 second clips. These are then converted to mel spectrums (now greyscale as per your comment). The is then fed into a ML.NET NRR+RESNET50 image classification model. Then when making a prediction I'll use this same pipeline to move the audio into the image domain, then run the prediction. So yes, a multi-label classification task.

Comment: What would be examples for your predictions? "Guitar", "Fast", "D-minor"?

Comment: Unfortunately, the ML.NET Model builder demands a single layer directory structure when building. So RootDir -> LabelDir -> *.png. So I have "Guitar Electric" "Guitar Acoustic" etc.

Comment: Ah! So you're doing *instrument classification*. To save some computing power, you might want to downsample to 22050 Hz, just because that will still be good enough. Also, you are using an FFT with length 8192 and a step size of 500, Typically, half-overlapping windows are good enough, so with `N=8192`, `stepsize=N/2` is often a sensible choice. In essence, stepsize defines your temporal resolution, and FFT length your frequency resolution. Since you're converting to Mel anyway, your frequency resolution probably does not need to be super high. You could experiment with N=4096, or even lower.

Comment: Wow ... that little nugget right there I can already tell will have a massive impact on the spectrograms I'll end up with. Thank you for this Hendrik.